# Set Active Cell on Close

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a macro assigned to a specific cell on single click that launches a date picker calendar.

Unfortunately, when my workbook gets closed, that same cell remains the active cell on next open.

This causes the next user to have to click on another cell, then click back to the macro'd cell to launch the calendar.

What I am looking to accomplish is something that will make another cell active on close or save of the workbook. This way, when a person opens the workbook they only need to click once on the macro'd cell to launch the calendar.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to call macros on the workbook open/close events already?

Comment: What does your `worksheet_selection` code look like, and what does your `calendar` code look like?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your macro, you can simply add one line to the effect of:

```
activesheet.range("ZZ999").select
```

Pick some cell far out. No need to create a separate sub.

Comment: Note that it isn't just the macro that's an issue - if the user then selects a particular cell before closing the file, the same problem will occur on opening. Solution would need to utilize the OnClose / OnSave property to ensure this (or Jeeped's solution).

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Uh if the user selects any other cell than the one that triggers the macro during use, then OP wouldn't have this problem upon opening of book next time. It's clear that user opens book, click trigger cell and nothing else? Edit: you mean Gary?

Comment: Not sure why OP doesn't build a button XD

Comment: Never underestimate the power of a fool when making something foolproof... And yes - mean't @Gary'sStudent; my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a macro:

```
Sub NewActiveCell()
'NewActiveCell Macro
Range("AA8").Select
End Sub
```

And then

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()    
NewActiveCell    
End Sub
```

I probably made it more complicated than it needs to be, but it worked

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `Application.Goto` to `Select`

So in the *ThisWorkbook* module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.Goto Sheets("YourSheet").[A1]
End Sub
```